# Passing a value from an application to another one

Tags: android

I have 2 separate applications.  From App1, I need to pass the location/destination to App2 so it will show in a popup.

I have tried Intents, SharedPreferences and even tried understanding ContentProviders (not good).  Nothing seems to work.

### Edit

Code using:

**App1: com.myapp.rider** - sending from rider app to driver app

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.myapp.driver.Activities.DriverTracking");
intent.putExtra("destination", destination);
startActivity(intent);
```

**App2: com.myapp.driver** - receiving value from rider

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
mDestination = (String) bundle.get("destination");
Log.d("STATUS_1", "Destination = " + mDestination);
```

**Add to Manifest in App2:**

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.myapp.driver.Activities.DriverTracking" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The above I have tried and get following error:

```
 Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.myapp.driver.Activities.DriverTracking (has extras) }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1878)
```

**Images**

[image]

### Edit

Here is the error:

```
05-27 14:45:12.940 21851-21851/com.myapp.rider E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.rider, PID: 21851
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.rider/com.myapp.rider.Activities.RiderHome}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.content.Intent.putExtras(android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.content.Intent.putExtras(android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
    at com.myapp.rider.Activities.RiderHome.sendIntent(RiderHome.java:355)
```

Comment: "I have 2 separate applications. From App1, I need to pass the location/destination to App2 so it will show in a popup as an address" -- in App1, call `startActivity()`, pointing to a dialog-themed activity ("popup as an address"). Pass the "location/destination" in some `Parcelable` form or in some `String` representation as an extra. "Nothing seems to work" -- it will be difficult for anyone to help you with that, since you have not provided a [mcve] and explained what your specific symptoms are.

Comment: Content provider is the simple answer for this

Comment: I would do a content provider but I don't know how I would do this.  I have tried to understand it, but its complicated.  Any idea of a good example or tutorial?

Comment: [The official Android Developers tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating) seems enough to me. And yes, **reading** is a must.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed solution with Intent+Bundle+PackageManager:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.myapp.driver", "com.myapp.driver.Activities.DriverTracking"));
intent.putExtra("destination", destination);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the Activity in second App you need to obtain the Bundle values:

```
String destination = getIntent().getStringExtra("destination");
```

Comment: I tried the above code ... and got this error on the RiderApp pointing to the Intent - Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.content.Intent.putExtra(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Ok, so post the error log. But I thought that `com.myapp.driver.Activities.DriverTracking` is the path to your Activity class in the second App, isn't? If no, pass them that Activity class name with full path + package name.

Comment: yes, the activity I am trying to send the value is "com.myapp.driver.Activities.DriverTracking

Comment: @LizG I customized the answer, check it

Comment: Got this error from revised: 
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myapp.driver/com.myapp.driver.Activities.DriverTracking}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

> App1: com.myapp.rider - sending from rider app to driver app

You are setting up an `Intent` that is expecting there to be some `<activity>` with an `<intent-filter>` that has an `<action>` of `com.myapp.driver.Activities.DriverTracking`.

> Add to Manifest in App2:

Here, your action is `com.myapp.ryyde_driver.Activities.DriverTracking`. This does not match your `Intent`. You need to make the action in the `Intent` match the `<action>` in the `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: My bad - autocomplete changed the driver to ryyde_driver, see images to show that. they are the same.

Comment: @LizG: And, with this fixed code, do you still get an `ActivityNotFoundException`? If so, then you need to determine whether the App 2 that is installed on your test device has the revised `<intent-filter>` with the revised `<action>`.

Comment: @LizG: That is a separate problem, stemming from some bug in your `RiderHome` class. Examine line 355 of `RiderHome` and try to determine how you are triggering a `NullPointerException` there. If you cannot determine that, ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a fresh [mcve] (e.g., the Java stack trace, plus your code that is referenced in that stack trace).

Comment: the code it is referring to is the intent - line 355 is pointing to this "intent.putExtras(b);" in the following intent: 
String secondAppActivityName = "com.devhopes.ryyde_driver.Activities.DriverTracking";
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(secondAppActivityName);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("destination", destination);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        if (intent != null)
            startActivity(intent);

Comment: @LizG: `getLaunchIntentForPackage(secondAppActivityName)` is returning `null`. That method does not take an activity name as a parameter. It takes a package name (i.e., your `applicationId` from `build.gradle`, or your `package` from the manifest if you do not override it in `build.gradle`).

Comment: I tried just putting in package name, applicationId and same errors

Comment: @LizG: Then perhaps you do not have a launcher `<intent-filter>`. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a fresh [mvce].